# Preciso da tag prisma

Tags: debate, status-pronto

Estou precisando criar uma nova tag para a linguagem prisma. Quem pode fazer isto pra mim?

Já criei uma pergunta mas não consigo adicionar uma tag porque não tenho 300 pontos de reputação.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219639/4808

Answer (score 2):

O usuário [Renan](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4808) adicionou a tag solicitada ao referido post, vide [histórico de edições](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/219639/3) da pergunta.